# How to maintain the state of CupertinoSegmentedControl for Internationalization?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I'm currently using internationalization from this link:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2

But I change the buttons to CupertinoSegmentedControl instead.

[image]

The problem is the segment keep losing state when I leave the page.

I tried using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but still didn't work.

Any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by losing state? They revert back to English when you select Bahasa?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo yes exactly, you got me!

Comment: you need to save/retrieve values from something like [shared_prefs](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: @MohamedSayed it's seems that you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you need to save/restore values, give [shared_prefs](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferrences) a try

I'll do it using my plugin [localize_and_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_and_translate)

Here is a simple implementation for it

1. You get the active language code with method it will return language code : `en` for example

   `translator.currentLanguage();`

2.You save to `shared_prefs` like following

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('code', translator.currentLanguage());
```

3. Retrive like following inside your widget tree

```
prefs.getString('code') == 'en' ? // widget for true : // widget for false,
```

Or  you can simply use my plugin directly without `shared_prefs`

```
translator.currentLanguage() == 'en' ? // widget for true : // widget for false,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still struggling to create logic to save the value in shared_prefs based on the detected locale and show it on the groupValue from CupertinoSegmentedControl. Can you please elaborate with a more concrete implementation?